# unix find command with mtime - unexpected result

Tags: unix, find

Sorry, annoying little question which no-one in my office seems able to answer...

The following command on our Linux system (ksh):

```
find . -mtime -3 -exec ls -lrt {} \;
```

...I would expect to list all files modified less than 3 days ago.

However, what I am getting is a list of all files in the current directory PLUS extra entries at the bottom for the 2 files (names made up, full details omitted for clarity) that are actually less than 3 days old ie.

```
...
fred.txt
john.sh
./fred.txt
./john.sh
```

I've tried using '-execdir' but makes no difference. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: Add `-type f` to limit your search to files. You're probably finding directories that have been modified in the last 3 days as well, and the `ls` lists their contents. Better yet: `find . -type f -mtime -3 -ls` (or `-print` instead of `-ls` if you just want file name).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` is finding the current directory.  I.e.,

```
$ find . -mtime -3
.
$
```

Which means `find` is doing an `ls -lrt .`, which prints everything.